# How do I fix this Discord.JS CommandHandler code?

Tags: discord.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const prefix = ("d");
const client = new Discord.Client ();

client.on("ready", async () => {
console.log(`${client.user.username} is now working online!`);
});

client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let command = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1);

   if(!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;

});

client.login("MY TOKEN");
```

When I try doing the command: "dhelp" that I've made and coded for example, it doesn't work. Why is this? People have said that I need a command handler and I think it's done but don't why it is still not working, why is this? Please help me, I really need help right now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start off, it doesn't actually look like your code does anything regardless of what the value of `command` is. Perhaps using `if/else` statements would be a good place to start.

```
if (command === "help") {
  /* some code here */
}
```

where `/* some code here */` is the code for your bot.

Comment: Not really, but okay?